# Change the length of a line and keep same width?

Tags: windows, inkscape

How do I resize a line without changing the width of the line in [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/)?

Scenario: I have already drawn a horizontal line and want to make it longer. If I select the line, use the resize handle to the middle right and resize then the width of the line
becomes larger as I drag to right to make the line longer. The Shift, Ctrl and Alt keyboard modifiers do not seem to have the desired effect either.

I have looked through the tutorials available from http://www.inkscape.org/doc/ and
checked the [Inkscape FAQ](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ)

---

Platform: Inkscape v0.46 (2008-03-10), Windows XP 64 bit, 8 GB RAM.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On the far right side of the Tool Controls Bar, you'll find four buttons (to the right of the "Affect:" label; see the screenshot below). You can use those to control which aspects of an object are affected by, e.g. resizing operations.

[image: The four "affect" buttons on the Tool Controls Bar]

Comment: This button says exactly what I want but doesn't actually do anything for me. `v0.91 r13725`

Answer (score 5):

Select the Edit Paths by Nodes tool and grab one end of the path. You can then move it around. If you're using freehand lines it's a bit more complicated but the principle is the same (you have to move multiple nodes).

Comment: Doesn't this only work for paths (not lines)?

Comment: Lines are paths, they just have only two nodes.